# is it possible to have a image (.png) over a button and still be able to click the button

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to have a image (.png) over a button and still be able to click that button

[image]

Comment: Here you have some answers. [1-Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488005/how-to-put-a-jpg-or-png-image-into-a-button-in-html) [2-Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920076/html-css-how-to-add-image-icon-to-input-type-button) ;-)

Comment: You should set for image `pointer-events: none;`. Just be aware of [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Comment: as you are using png image, you can use it as a background and easily you can position the button as per requirement showed in screenshot or you an use absolute position for the button too possible.. like this https://jsfiddle.net/3qxjbrL9/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments...without adjusting the `z-index` of the image (which is apparently not an option) you are restricted to disabling pointer events on the image.

```
img {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

[**Support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) is all modern browsers but only IE11

Poor Demo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
button {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `z-index`, you can indeed:

```
button.btn-class {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

EDIT - You'll obviously need to ensure the image `z-index` is lower that 999 as above!

Good reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: But then the button would be over the image

Comment: The image should be on top, not the button.

Comment: @A.Wolff Apologies I mis-read the question - I'll delete my answer!

Comment: @RaduDragan as above, I mis-read the question, I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes use higher z-index value for button than image. For more info refer this **[link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)**

```
img{z-index:9;}

button{z-index:99;}
```

Comment: But that doesn't set the image over the button then. EDIT: seeing screenshot, if elements get always being displayed that way, it could be a solution indeed

Comment: The image should be on top, not the button.

Comment: post your code as a demo, so we can help better

Comment: http://fotodex.ro/constructor/test/

Comment: no it`s not http://www.fotodex.ro/constructor/test/

Comment: still, url not working in any of my browsers..

Comment: i have no idear way is used http://www.isup.me/ and it`s telling me "it`s up", thanks

Answer (score 1):

z-index property of css only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

use this:

```
.imgclass {
    position: relative; //or whatever you want i.e fixed
    z-index: -1;
}

.buttonclass {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: The image should be on top, not the button.

Comment: Ok, as your query you can not do this....

Comment: you will not be able to click/hover the button because html elements are like  stacks....

Comment: you can see here way z-index this is not an answer http://fotodex.ro/constructor/test/

Comment: [fotodex.ro/constructor/test/](http://fotodex.ro/constructor/test/) This web page is not available